# Play audio on Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, audio

I´m workin with Ionic 6 and Angular (Capacitor)

I want to play an audio from the next site (http://138.91.126.10:1011/PLAZA%20MAY%20AUDIOGUIA.wav) but it don't work, on my browser it works very well but on a mobile device it don't work.

Wen I change the source (http://138.91.126.10:1011/PLAZA%20MAY%20AUDIOGUIA.wav) to (../../assets/media/Audio1.mp3) it both works

what can I do to play the audio from (http://138.91.126.10:1011/PLAZA%20MAY%20AUDIOGUIA.wav) on my movil device?

This is my code:
`<audio controls>      <source src="http://138.91.126.10:1011/PLAZA%20MAY%20AUDIOGUIA.wav" type="audio/wav" />   </audio>`

I did try use howlerJS but i get the same problem, it work whit (../../assets/media/Audio1.mp3) but no work with  (http://138.91.126.10:1011/PLAZA%20MAY%20AUDIOGUIA.wav)

Answer (score 0):

you should look at Ionic Native's documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio

```
$ npm install cordova-plugin-nativeaudio
$ npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/native-audio
$ ionic cap sync
```

then

```
import { NativeAudio } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/native-audio/ngx';

constructor(private nativeAudio: NativeAudio) { }

...

this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('uniqueId1', 'path/to/file.mp3').then(onSuccess, onError);
this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('uniqueId2', 'path/to/file2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then(onSuccess, onError);

this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1').then(onSuccess, onError);

// can optionally pass a callback to be called when the file is done playing
this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1', () => console.log('uniqueId1 is done playing'));

this.nativeAudio.loop('uniqueId2').then(onSuccess, onError);

this.nativeAudio.setVolumeForComplexAsset('uniqueId2', 0.6).then(onSuccess,onError);

this.nativeAudio.stop('uniqueId1').then(onSuccess,onError);

this.nativeAudio.unload('uniqueId1').then(onSuccess,onError);
```

To go further Ionic Native also offers music controls https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/music-controls

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding the line `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in the document **android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

picture 1
[usesCleartextTraffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoFQM.png)

picture 2
[permission.INTERNET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3966.png)

Comment: To more help, you can go here: https://programmerclick.com/article/7117706394/